# Результат запроса не распознает русские буквы - Терадата

Tags: teradata

После переустановки Терадаты результат запроса в полях с русскими буквами выдает пустоту вместо слов, что делать?

Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего проблема c кодировкой.
В настройках подключения клиента, проверьте настройки Session Character Set.